# PHP: По ключу не получается вытащить значение

Tags: php, массивы, xml, циклы, объекты

Со следующим кодом:

```
foreach($xml as $result) {
                $d = $result->attributes()["Target"];
    
                print_r($d);
                exit;
    }
```

в переменной $d оказывается следующая конструкция:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если пытаюсь сделать так: print_r($d[0]) или так: $d = $result->attributes()["Target"][0], то ничего не происходит. Опять возвращается объект с массивом внутри, а не строка, ключом для которой является [0].

Пробовал даже так: $d = $result->attributes()["Target"]->{0}. Результат тот же.

В дебаггере следующая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Пример входного XML:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну наверняка у объекта работающего с xml есть методы доставания текста, не правда ли? типа getText или что-то подобное

Comment: Пример xml можно увидеть?

Comment: Можно попробовать кастануть `$d` в строку: `$dStr = (string) $d;`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский приложил к задаче скрин-пример xml, который разбирается..

Comment: Не нужно скрин, нужно текстом...для тестов....и где там Target? чёт не вижу

Comment: @u_mulder спасибо, реализовал вашу идею и все заработало, у меня осталась только ссылка, а ключ исчез.. как это получилось не понимаю, но сработало!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский конкретно тот файл не могу предоставить, к сожалению, там конф. информация. Но, по сути дела, проблема решилась! Предложение u_muldera сработало. Спасибо и Вам, Алексей, что уделили время!

Comment: @u_mulder кстати, с таким же успехом можно было поменять print_r на echo

Comment: @splash58 можно да, но вдруг эту строку куда-то надо записать или еще что.